# Blazor - Add Active Class to Current Element

Tags: blazor

Trying to develop a website fully in Blazor

I'm trying to figure out how to add e.g. active class to the currently selected element.
I have a side menu bar and it would be awesome to know on which page the user is.

Found this [JavaScript solution](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp) but I wanted to do it via #c

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.NavLink component automatically adds "active" class (or a class of a your choosing). Example code below.

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.navlink?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

Use NavLink tag for navigating between pages in Blazor. There is an attribute called NavLinkMatch which will automatically apply "active" class for you whenever current route would be matched.

For more information, check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#navlink-component

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

as always binding
define a property and bind in class="style @prop"

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use NavMatchLink.All or NavMatchLink.Prefix which sets active class based on the URL, NavMatchLink.All can be used for static or dedicated pages where NavLink href URL matches with display title of link, now if you are Rendering NavLink inside loop, then its better to add Display Title of the link in the URL for ex /ActionMethod/{Parameter}?&Title = {Link Display Name} and use NavMatchLink.Prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a solution that didn't require BootStrap and this was the first match. If anyone else is looking at this, remember to include the StateHasChanged() in your EventHandler!!

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-nav @isActive" @onclick=NavTo>@display</button>

@code {
    [Inject] NavigationManager _navMan { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Destination { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Display { get; set; }
    string display => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Display) ? Destination : Display;
    string isActive = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        _navMan.LocationChanged += UpdateLoc;
    }
    async Task NavTo() {
        _navMan.NavigateTo($"/{Destination}");
    }
    void UpdateLoc(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args) {
        isActive = args.Location.Replace(_navMan.BaseUri, "") == Destination ? "active" : "";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, Here is my solutions

**Solution 1:**
With this solution, if the user refresh the page, the active item will change.

```
@page "/test"
<div>
  <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("1")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("1"))">1</button>
  <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("2")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("2"))">2</button>
  <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("3")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("3"))">3</button>
  <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("4")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("4"))">4</button>
  <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("5")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("5"))">5</button>
</div>

@code {
  public string activeItem = "1";

  public void SetActive(string item)
   {
      activeItem = item;
      StateHasChanged();
   }

  public string IsActive(string item) =>
      item == activeItem ? " active" : "";
}
```

**Solution 2**
With this solution, if the user refresh the page, the active item will be preserved.

```
@page "/test/{activeItem?}"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@*This section is the same in both solutions*@
<div>
    <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("1")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("1"))">1</button>
    <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("2")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("2"))">2</button>
    <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("3")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("3"))">3</button>
    <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("4")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("4"))">4</button>
    <button class=@($"btn {IsActive("5")}") @onclick="@(() => SetActive("5"))">5</button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? ActiveItem { get; set; }

    private string defaultActiveItem = "1";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (ActiveItem is null)
        {
            ActiveItem = defaultActiveItem;
        }
    }

    public void SetActive(string item)
    {
        ActiveItem = item;
        // will not reload the page but only modify URL.
        Navigation.NavigateTo($"/test/{ActiveItem}");
    }

    public string IsActive(string item) =>
        item == ActiveItem ? " active" : "";
}
```

Sorry if my English is poor.